# Как определить, что логический диск имеет read-only атрибут?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Получаю список дисков функцией `GetLogicalDriveStrings`.

В компьютер вставлена флешка, у флешки переключатель защиты от записи может быть 
включен, а может быть не включен. Соответственно, при защите от записи пользователя нужно уведомить. Как определить, что флешка (и\или логический диск) недоступна для записи?

Comment: GetVolumeInformation и FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME?

Comment: А почему банально попробовать записать пустой файл и удалить нельзя? Или  это решение не для перфекционистов? :)

Comment: @Albert Fomin, в этом случае ОС выбросит неотлавливаемый эксепшн

Comment: Да ладно! if fileexists(fileclose(filecreate('test123456789.txt'))) then даже без try except сработает. Хотя лучше поставить конечно. И всё. Если файла нет, удаляем его

Comment: @Albert Fomin, я вам рекомендую вставить флешку с переключателем на lock и попробовать ваше решение. Увидите то, о чем я говорю.
Напомню, вылетит exception, который не ловится связкой try-except

Comment: @Albert Fomin, но даже если бы это сработало - получился бы костыль через пятую точку(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому пригодится

```
function CheckDiskReadOnlyAttribute(volumePath: string): Boolean;
var
  MaximumComponentLength: DWord;
  SystemFlags: Cardinal;
const
  FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME = $00080000;
begin
  Result := False;

  if GetVolumeInformation(PChar(volumePath), nil, 0, nil,
    MaximumComponentLength, SystemFlags, nil, 0) then
  begin
    Result := ((SystemFlags and FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME) = FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME);
  end;
end;
```